# how to convert Data to Int in swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, type-conversion

I'm coding in Swift. API returns a Data which need to be converted to Int! what should I do?

the response that I need looks like::

> 12345

but the think I get when I print data is :

> Optional(5 bytes)

API returns an Int (not JSON)

```
//send HTTP req to register user
        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://app.avatejaratsaba1.com/api/Person/Create")
        var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST" // compose a query string
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let postString = ["name" : name.text!,
                          "isLegal" : FinalLegalSegment,
                          "codeMelli" : National_ID.text! ] as [String : Any]


do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options: .prettyPrinted)
        }catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            self.DisplayMessage(UserMessage: "1Something went wrong , please try again!")
            return
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
        {
            (data : Data? , response : URLResponse? , error : Error?) in

            self.removeActivtyIndicator(activityIndicator: MyActivityIndicator)

            if error != nil
            {
                self.DisplayMessage(UserMessage: "2Could not successfully perform this request , please try again later.")
                print("error = \(String(describing : error))")
                return
            }
            else
            {

                print("////////////////////////////////")
                print("data has been sent")

            }
        }



        task.resume()
```

Comment: in which line you got 12345 ?

Comment: I don't get this number out of my code! API should send it back

Comment: add json api code.bcs in your code any devs not understand whats problem

Comment: pls add this line in your if else part print(response)

Comment: send me what u got

Comment: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000438c00> { URL: http://app.avatejaratsaba1.com/api/Person/Create } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sat, 30 Jun 2018 11:18:57 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        Kestrel
    );
    "Transfer-Encoding" =     (
        Identity
    );
    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        "ASP.NET"
    );
} })

Comment: add this code in if else part and check         let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)
                    print(jsonResponse as! NSDictionary)

Comment: i get :: " Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'  "  in the begining of   let tas =...

Comment: I cannot find any `a` defined in your code... What do you get when you put `print(data! as NSData)` in the place of `print(a)`.

Comment: that is a comment! I've been trying something myself

Comment: So, what do you get with `print(data! as NSData)` ?

Comment: i get "   <32383136 33>  "

Comment: This is number is not the integer that i'm looking for!!!

Comment: It repesents "28163" in ASCII compatible code (including UTF-8). Is it not the number you want?

Comment: this is what I want ( 28163) how should I get this?

Comment: You have two ways, decode it as JSON and convert the result into some integer, or directly decode it as String and then convert it to an integer.

Comment: which one is better and which one do you recommend?

Comment: As you are specifying `application/json` for `Accept` in your request header I would choose JSON, but it may be less efficient.

Comment: then what excatly should i add to my code ? and how did you get 28163?

Comment: Your server is sending the text representation of the integer in ASCII compatible encoding. I just have decoded it. You need to do it with your code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with asci codes ! could you explain more?

Comment: you can convert data into string and than you can user Int initializers to instantiate int from string

Comment: @RahulGUsai could you send the code you mean! i don't know swift very well

Comment: let stringInt = String.init(data: yourdata, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        
 let int = Int.init(stringInt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first convert your data into string like blow and then use that string to initialize int

```
let stringInt = String.init(data: yourdata, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
let int = Int.init(stringInt ?? "")
```

this will return an optional value which you can unwrap to use further

Comment: Those `.init` s are not needed. Note  also that `Int.init(stringInt)` won't compile because `stringInt` is an optional.

Comment: yes you can use it without init like java style but that how i write code for getting know that something it getting initialized here

Comment: and for optionals i have already mentioned that above sentences will return optional values and you have to unwrap it

Answer (score 9):

one can use withUnsafeBytes to get the pointer and load the integer

```
let x = data.withUnsafeBytes({

        (rawPtr: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
        return rawPtr.load(as: Int32.self)

        })
```

rawPtr is unsaferawbufferpointer and the load() helps to return the value to x. 
This can be used for getting any integer. The rawPtr is a temporary pointer and it must not be used outside the block.

This is available since Swift 5 and the older version had

```
public func withUnsafeBytes<ResultType, ContentType>(_ body: (UnsafePointer<ContentType>) throws -> ResultType) rethrows -> ResultType
```

which is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

`let intValue: Int = yourData.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }`

`withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }` will return a generic type, you can cast it to your known type.

Comment: You should add a longer explanation to why this would help, and how/where to use it. It avoids people just copy/paste-ing code without actually understanding it

Comment: Additionally, please add such explanation to the answer itself, not to the comment section

Comment: 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in my comment, your server sends text representation of  an integer.

You need to write something like this:

```
if error != nil
{
    //...
    return
}
else
{
    if let data = data {
        //First convert the data into String
        if let text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            //And then into Int
            if let value = Int(text) {
                print(value)
                //... use the value
            } else {
                print("text cannot be converted to Int")
            }
        } else {
            print("data is not in UTF-8")
        }
    } else {
        print("data == nil")
    }
}
```

The code above might be simpler, if you do not need some `print`s.

---

Using `guard` as suggested by Martin R, the code above looks something like this:

```
    guard let data = data else {
        print("data == nil")
        return
    }
    guard let text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
        print("data is not in UTF-8")
        return
    }
    guard let value = Int(text) else {
        print("text cannot be converted to Int")
        return
    }
    print(value)
    //... use the value
```

You can avoid deeply nested code using `guard`. (You can use `guard` for checking `error != nil`, but I leave that for you.)

Comment: @MartinR, nice suggestion, I'v almost forgotten.